# array beyod bounds?

Tags: objective-c

we are trying to add objects to an array  , and when its full( capacity=10) , to shift all the values forward and erase the first (such as shift register)

i was trying to do the next and it allways crash after 10, because 9 beyond bounds of 8..??

```
if (count>9)
{

    for(count=0;count<9;count++)    
    {
            NSLog(@"%@",listOfEvents);
        [listOfEvents removeObjectAtIndex:count];
        [listOfEvents insertObject:[listOfEvents objectAtIndex:(count+1)] atIndex:count];

    }
    [listOfEvents removeObjectAtIndex:9];   
    [listOfEvents insertObject:event atIndex: 9];       
}


else
        [listOfEvents addObject:event];

count++;
```

when i have tried without removing object ,i get another error .
what am i doing wrong?
why cant i add values to some index, when there is a space index befor him? ?
thanks a lot .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually have to do it this way, since `NSArray` will perform the "downsliding" of elements on its own:

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index.

([NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

So

```
if (count > 9) [array removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
[array addObject: newObject];
```

should be sufficient. `NSMutableArray` behaves more like an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in Java, or a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in C#, and less like a plain C array.

Answer (score 2):

When in your inner loop `count` is `8`, you are accessing the object at index `9`, which is out of bounds. Make the loop one shorter, and get rid off the `removeObject` just after the loop.

(You are not moving anything *into* the final slot.)

An alternative implementation of a ring buffer would avoid moving elements around and just keep a pointer to the current end of the buffer, so you would dynamically compute your *indexes* dynamically (in constant time), rather than move the objects around.

Comment: thanks a lot i understand that , but WHY IS IT OUT OF BOUND?? my array bound is 10 so the index is 0-9 ! i just cant understand that bound thing. ALSO, even if i was beyond bounds, he has to auto enlarge my array no ?

Comment: `NSMutableArrays` adjust their size whenever elements are added or deleted. And when the size is adjusted, so is the range of acceptable indices.

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks. @Rant: So it might be an alternative to *copy* the element down from `count+1` to `count`, and never remove any elements.

Comment: thanks a lot both. its working. but still, i was in the bounds, 0-9 ,so its strange, but ok :)